# PTIJ: What does Purim have to do with Pesach?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There's a Gezeria Shava between Purim and Pesach (the phrase מי יודע - אחד מי יודע to )וּמִי יוֹדֵעַ אִם לְעֵת כָּזֹאת הִגַּעַתְּ לַמַּלְכוּת

What else does the above Gezeira Shava teach us?

[Small meta question - Is the tree up there connected to Haman's 50 Amah tree?]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

There is one glaringly obvious connection - the feast of Achashverosh described in the first chapter of Megillat Esther was in fact a Seder.

1. They had [*karpas*](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as well as [couches for reclining](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).
2. [והשתיה כדת](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - the wine was drunk in accordance with the rules of the 4 cups.
3. [אין אנס](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - no one was forced to eat the *matzah*.

This is because they were *choshesh* for the opinion of the [Maggid Mishneh to Hilchot Shofar 2:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Maggid_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah,_Shofar,_Sukkah_and_Lulav.2.4.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the correct text of the Rambam in [Hilchot Chametz uMatza 6:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Leavened_and_Unleavened_Bread.6.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) may read

> אכל מצה בלא כונה כגון שאנסוהו עכו"ם או לסטין לאכול לא יצא ידי חובתו
>
> If one ate *matzah* unintenionally, for instance if he was forced by non-Jews or bandits to eat, he has not fulfilled his obligation.

4. But then they had a problem. They couldn't find any *maror*. Achachverosh therefore needed to [summon Vashti](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), so they could contemplate the relevant verse in [Kohelet 7:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.7.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [thus remember the bitterness](http://seforim.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/halakhah-and-haggadah-manuscript.html). Vashti was naturally insulted by this suggestion, [and refused to come](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).
5. Finally, at the very end of the seder, Achashverosh [called for Charvona](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), who, as we all know, [is actually Eliyahu HaNavi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37460&st=&pgnum=203&hilite=).

Answer (score 3):

In [Shemuel B 12:22](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemuel_II/12.22#e0n7) it explains the outcome of the Gezeirah Shavah:

> **צַ֖מְתִּי** וָאֶבְכֶּ֑ה כִּ֤י אָמַ֙רְתִּי֙ **מִ֣י יוֹדֵ֔עַ**

This proves that there must be a fast day prior to reciting "Mi Yodeya".  For this reason, we have Taanis Bechorim on Erev Pesach, and Taanis Esther before Purim!